# I am new to Vue, How can i send the ID to Function so that i can add it in the Cart data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working Laravel and Vue, I am new to Vue and i am trying random stuff just to learn, i cant figure out on how to send the employee id to the AddToCart function. I would appreciate help

[image: Template]

Comment: Just a tip: It would be better if you post your code as text and format it using SO formatting. Code images are very hard to deal with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add it as a parameter on the function call:

```
<a :href="employees.id" @click="AddToCart(employees.id)">Cart</a>
```

And then, add the parameter on the method and set cart:

```
methods: {
  AddToCart(id) {
    //Do something with ID
  }
}
```